# сокращенная запись grid-template

Tags: css, css3, css-grid

1. есть 2 вида записи grid-template первая запись в коде означает ...
2. grid-template первых 2 числа (300px) будут равны grid-template-rows получим 2 строки
3. grid-template значения после слеша (/) это 2 числа по 200px будут равны grid-template-columns

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 300px 300px / 200px 200px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="">1</div>
    <div class="">2</div>
    <div class="">3</div>
    <div class="">4</div>
  </div>
```

4. Как понимать 2 способ записи grid-template ? 
   (html код выложить не могу)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: [start] "post-1 post-1 post-2" 200px [row2] 
                  [row2] "post-1 post-1 post-3"  200px [row3]
                  [row3] "post-6 post-5 post-4" 200px [row-end] / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.post-1 { 
  grid-area: post-1;  
}
.post-2 { 
  grid-area: post-2;  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё очень просто.

Параметр `grid-template` может иметь несколько входных параметров, как Вы верно указали - высоту строк и ширину колонок.

Параметр `grid-template: 300px 300px / 200px 200px;` это тоже самое что и

```
   grid-template-rows: 300px 300px;
   grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
```

Например, указав в первом разделе `grid-template` несколько размеров - Вы тем самым задаёте несколько строк в Вашей табличной форме. 
К примеру, указав третий, четвёртый, пятый и т.п. параметры, Вы тем самым задаёте высоту каждой из строк.

Пример(Задаём первую и вторую строку высоту 100px, а у третей строки высоту 300px):

```css
    .grid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template: 100px 100px 300px / 200px 200px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="">1</div>
    <div class="">2</div>
    <div class="">3</div>
    <div class="">4</div>
    <div class="">5</div>
    <div class="">6</div>
    <div class="">7</div>
    <div class="">8</div>
</div>
```

Тоже самое можно сделать и с колонками - задать определённый размер для каждой колонки. 
Например(В данном примере, мы задаём 4 колонки, у первых 2 будет ширина 50px, у третьей авто, у последней 100px. В этом случае все колонки кроме третьей будут иметь фиксированный размер, а третья же будет подстраиваться под остальные имея автоматическую установку размера.)

```css
    .grid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template: 300px 300px 400px / 50px 50px auto 100px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="">1</div>
    <div class="">2</div>
    <div class="">3</div>
    <div class="">4</div>
    <div class="">5</div>
    <div class="">6</div>
    <div class="">7</div>
</div>
```

Всё тоже самое можно задать и через параметры `grid-template-rows` и `grid-template-columns`. 
В последнем примере это будет

```
    grid-template-rows: 300px 300px 400px;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 50px auto 100px;
```

Теперь что касается второго Вашего вопроса.

При помощи указания параметров `[start]` `[row2]` и так далее в `grid-template` это тоже самое, что указывать данные параметры через
`grid-row-start, grid-column-start, grid-row-end и grid-column-end` именуя строки(тоже самое возможно со столбцами)
То-есть таким образом Вы задаёте какая колонка или какая строка будет иметь подобные значения.

Например(В данном примере, мы именуем их и указываем для каждой строки свой размер - первая строка от начала до 2 строки будет иметь высоту в 200px, начиная со второй строки и до третьей высота будет 40px, с третьей по самый конец - 100px):

```css
    .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template: [start] "post-1 post-1 post-2" 200px [row2]
        [row2] "post-1 post-1 post-3"  40px [row3]
        [row3] "post-6 post-5 post-4" 100px [row-end] / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="">1</div>
    <div class="">2</div>
    <div class="">3</div>
    <div class="">4</div>
    <div class="">5</div>
    <div class="">6</div>
    <div class="">7</div>
    <div class="">8</div>
</div>
```

Имена можно задавать любые. 
Для полного понимания ещё один пример с другими именами (Результат будет тот же, что и в предыдущем варианте, но названия строк будут другие):

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: [start] "post-1 post-1 post-2" 200px [row20]
    [row20] "post-1 post-1 post-3"  40px [row13]
    [row13] "post-6 post-5 post-4" 100px [row-end] / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="">1</div>
    <div class="">2</div>
    <div class="">3</div>
    <div class="">4</div>
    <div class="">5</div>
    <div class="">6</div>
    <div class="">7</div>
    <div class="">8</div>
</div>
```

В случае с присваиванием имён - к ним можно будет в дальнейшем обращаться.

Ещё очень важный момент - это **распределение зон во всех наших ячейках.** 
Я специально не убирал параметры `post-1` и остальные для объяснения. 
Задавая таким образом, или через `grid-template-rows` и `grid-template-colums` зоны - Вы сможете помещать в нужную Вам зону нужный Вам элемент.

К примеру(В примере ниже в первой строке первые 2 столбца будут иметь название зоны `post-1` (Значит при добавлении элемента, он займёт все ячейки, которые имеют данный параметр, в данном случае 2 первых),
 во второй строке у нас все ячейки имеют свою собственную зону (при вставке параметра вставится именно в нужную одну ячейку)
 в третьей строке у нас первая ячейка имеет своё имя, в 2 последних одинаковое `post-7`(соответственно элемент помещённый в эту зону займёт эти 2 ячейки)

Ячейки можно располагать любым способом. 
(Для классов задаём параметр `grid-area`(тоже самое, что и задать параметры размеров вручную) к которому привязываем название имени конкретной зоны. 
Пример:

```css
    .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template: [start] "post-1 post-1 post-2" 100px[row20]
        [row20] "post-3 post-4 post-5"  40px [row13]
        [row13] "post-6 post-7 post-7" 100px [row-end] / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
    .stile1 {
        grid-area: post-1;
    }
    .stile2 {
        grid-area: post-4;
    }
    .stile3 {
        grid-area: post-7;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="">1</div>
    <div class="">2</div>
    <div class="">3</div>
    <div class="">4</div>
    <div class="">5</div>
    <div class="">6</div>
    <div class="">7</div>
    <div class="">8</div>
    <div class="stile1">Займёт первые 2 ячейки своим содержимым. Напишу больше текста, чтобы явно было видно.</div>
    <div class="stile2">Займёт одну ячейку</div>
    <div class="stile3">Займёт последние 2 ячейки своим содержимым. Напишу больше текста, чтобы явно было видно.</div>
</div>
```

Таким образом последние(по порядку) наши `div` размещаются не по порядку, а в нужную нам зону(привязанной к имени зоны), смещая остальные колонки, которые идут по порядку.
А так же они занимают нужное нам количество места, обозначенных именем зоны.

Многовато получилось информации, но всё достаточно просто.

Comment: у вас тут опечатка Пример(Задаём первую и вторую строку высоту 100px, а у третей строки высоту 300px):

Comment: @Leks Верно, спасибо за замечание - изменил.

Comment: пожалуйста как я понял grid-template: [start] "post-1 post-1 post-2" 200px [row2]  в квадратных скобках [] указывается имя линии сетки начало [start] и конец [row2] в двойных скобках указывается что называется grid-template-area; 200px это высота строки после слеша идет указание кол-во колонок и их размер правильно я понял ?

Comment: @Leks не совсем. Всё что в между `[start]` и `[row2]` (всё что в ковычках) это названия зон, в которые в дальнейшем можно помещать элементы. Высоту строки вы указываете в `[start] "post-1 post-1 post-2" 100px[row20]` где высока строки будет 100px. А ширину колонок указываете в конце `[row13] "post-6 post-7 post-7" 100px [row-end] / 1fr 1fr 1fr;` где `1fr 1fr 1fr` это ширина колонок. В данном случае свойство `area` присваивает классу ту самую проименованную зону.

Comment: 1fr 1fr 1fr это ширина колонок. должна быть всегда в конце grid-template ?

Comment: @Leks Да, всё верно, до `/` указываются параметры строк, после `/` параметры столбцов. Как в первом примере.

Comment: до вашего последнего коммента я исправил немного комментарий посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: @Leks Да, всё абсолютно точно.

Comment: спасибо что ответили на вопрос и комментарий, удачи

Comment: @Leks Спасибо, и Вам.